# Swift - Trouble Accessing Property from Subclass

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, subclass

So I'm new to swift and I have learned a little about accessing properties from a subclass. In this case I think my problem is more complicated than that however.

I have a tableview which segues to a detail view (BuyStats). And in the 'prepare' method I'm setting the property "selectedPlayer" for the BuyStats class.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "BuyStats" {

        let buyStats =  segue.destination as! BuyStats

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let player = players[indexPath.row]

            buyStats.selectedPlayer = player

        }
    }
```

selectedPlayer works fine here and I have no trouble accessing its .Name property.

```
class BuyStats: UIViewController {

var selectedPlayer: Player! = nil

@IBOutlet weak var selectedPlayerNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var spendAmount: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Enter", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)))
    self.title = "Buy Stats"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

    selectedPlayerNameLabel.text = selectedPlayer.Name

}
```

But within the detail view I also have a container view which holds a nav controller and a subclass of BuyStats. I also need to be able to access selectedPlayer in the subclass (BuyStatsTapPager), but its not working.

Heres a storyboard pic in case my setup is a little confusing.

[image]

This is where I need to access the selectedPlayer property from the super class.

```
class BuyStatsTabPager: BuyStats{

@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreKey: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var standings: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 27/255, blue: 27/255, alpha: 1)

    scoreKey.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
    scoreKey.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    standings.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
    standings.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

but the below print statement gives me a exc_bad_instruction error. Shouldn't this be available in the subclass if it is successfully set in the superclass?

```
  print(super.selectedPlayer.Name)

}
```

'selectedPlayer' shows up in the IDE without the call to super so I've also tried that.

```
print(selectedPlayer.Name)
```

I'm not having any luck with google and all of the other solutions I've been trying are a little wacky so I thought I better ask somebody.

Comment: It depends on how the instance of `BuyStatsTabPager` is created and the property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your storyboard looks like in your case the destination of your segue is not `BuyStats` but rather the navigation controller. In your `prepare(for: sender:)` method, try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "BuyStats" {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let buyStats = nav.viewControllers[0] as! BuyStatsTabPager

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let player = players[indexPath.row]
            buyStats.selectedPlayer = player

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out. I was trying to use class inheritance when I should have been using a second prepare for segue in the BuyStats class.